# How to get child nodes through importxml xpath query?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the seperate `<td>`'s to show up in Google Sheet of a `<tr>` that I'm importing through `IMPORTXML`.
This code should get my match data based on the match ID I provide, and my player ID. I feel that simply adding `/*` or `/td` to end of Xpath should work, but that's the end of my knowledge.

I tried: adding `/*`, `/td` and other to end of xPath Query but doesn't seem to work.
Even disabled JavaScript and inspected website again but to no avail.

FORMULA:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.dotabuff.com/matches/5011379854";"//tr[contains(@class,'9764136')]")
```

Also tried:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.dotabuff.com/matches/5011379854";"//td[parent::tr[contains(@class,'9764136')]]")
```

Which only gives the first of all the /td's and not the rest.

Current outputis all mushed together:

```
"19LemthTop (Off)ZeusCoreTop (Off)  Roaminglost27108.7k127933650626.5k-183-/-5m7m21m31m"
```

The output that I want is separate `<td>` on separate lines:

```
"19

LemthTop (Off)ZeusCoreTop (Off)  Roaminglost

2

7

10

8.7k

127

9

336

506

26.5k

-

183

-/-

5m7m21m31m"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Issue and workaround:

Although I have tried to parse the values for each row, unfortunately, it seemed that `td` cannot be directly parsed using a xpath with `IMPORTXML` as each row. But fortunately, each table can be retrieved by `IMPORTHTML` and also each tab can be accessed. Using them, how about the following workaround?

1. Retrieve a table from the URL using `IMPORTHTML`.
2. Retrieve a row including the name corresponding to `9764136` you want using a query.

### Modified formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("@",TRUE,QUERY(IMPORTHTML(A1,"table",1), "where Col4 contains '"&IMPORTXML(A1,"//a[contains(@href,'9764136')]")&"'", 0)),"@",TRUE,TRUE))
```

- The URL of `https://www.dotabuff.com/matches/5011379854` is put to the cell "A1".
- After the table was retrieved, the row is retrieved from the table by the query.

  - The important point of this workaround is the methodology. I think that there are various formulas for retrieving the value. So please think of above sample formula as just one of them.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- If you use above formula for other URL, an error might occur. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)
- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, this works perfectly. I stripped the transpose and emptry field skip and added an IFNA for the second tablr and now it works for every matchID that I'm importing. Good idea using the query on an importhtml.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for editing it and your always support.